# SQL - convert long integer to datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database with dates in the following long integer format:

20100101000000

Where that would be Jan 1st, 2010, 00:00:00 for the time of day.

I want to be able to convert this to normal SQL Datetime syntax and back. Is this possible? I can only get this far:

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as int);
```

Which returns '40556' - not exactly what Im after.

Comment: Don't save dates like this, use a regular timestamp.

Comment: I didnt create the database. Not really an answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `substring` to convert your string to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` notation, and cast that to a `datetime`:

```
select  convert(datetime, 
            substring(sub.Dt,1,4) + '-' + 
            substring(sub.Dt,5,2) + '-' + 
            substring(sub.Dt,7,2) + ' ' +
            substring(sub.Dt,9,2) + ':' + 
            substring(sub.Dt,11,2) + ':' + 
            substring(sub.Dt,13,2))
from    (
        select  '20100101000000' as Dt
        ) sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stuff it with the spaces and colons required:

```
select
stuff(stuff(stuff('20100101000000',9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':') STR,
convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff('20100101000000',9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) DT;
```

The result is

```
STR               | DT
20100101 00:00:00 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

The first one shows the string it is converted to, the 2nd the datetime value.
To go in reverse

```
select
convert(char(8),getdate(),112) + replace(convert(varchar(30),getdate(),108),':','');
```

Replace the constants '20100101000000' and "getdate()" with field names where required if selecting from a table.