# SQL Convert Integer to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table with column `fetchtime` in the following integer format:

```
20100903063110
20110403022433
20130203142033
20130103153313
```

and so on. Where that would be the date and time together (`YYYYMMDDHHMISS`)

I need to convert all records in this column to a SQL Server `DateTime` format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`

Once this is done, I want to extract the converted Date and Time format separately and store it in two new columns of the same table.

While looking for this I found the below mentioned conversion using substring by @Andomar but was unable to adapt this to my requirement.

```
select  
   convert(datetime, substring(sub.Dt,1,4) + '-' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,5,2) + '-' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,7,2) + ' ' +
                     substring(sub.Dt,9,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,11,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,13,2))
from      
    (select  '20100101000000' as Dt) sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the convert/substr? It looks like it does what you want?

Comment: While the value may be coincidentally stored as a numeric type, for the purposes of conversion that number has no meaningful date/time representation.  To that end, it needs to be treated as a string.  The existing approach (constructing a date/time from substrings) seems reasonable.

Comment: @AlexK. thanks for the reply. Yes, it does the conversion of only '20100101000000' value. How could I use this to make the conversion of all the records in the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jain, it looks like you are trying to adapt the code [in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697446/1225845) to your own situation.  What Andomar did there was to select the information from a subquery which contained only a single value, since he didn't have access to the original poster's source and tables. Doing it that way allows everyone to run and see it, whatever database schema they happen to have.

Adapting something like that to your own code would be very easy: just replace the `alias.column` reference (here, it was `sub.Dt`) with your own value, and put your table in the FROM clause instead of the subquery.  Thus, if your table was named `SomeTable`, and your column is named `FetchTime`, the query becomes:

```
select  
   convert(datetime, substring(SomeTable.FetchTime,1,4) + '-' + 
                     substring(SomeTable.FetchTime,5,2) + '-' + 
                     substring(SomeTable.FetchTime,7,2) + ' ' +
                     substring(SomeTable.FetchTime,9,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(SomeTable.FetchTime,11,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(SomeTable.FetchTime,13,2))
from      
    SomeTable
```

You could theoretically have a problem if your `FetchTime` field was stored as an integer: [SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) might not work on that data type.  To work around that, you could `CAST()` the value as varchar, like this:

```
select  
   convert(datetime, substring(CAST(SomeTable.FetchTime AS VARCHAR(20)),1,4) + '-' + 
                     substring(CAST(SomeTable.FetchTime AS VARCHAR(20)),5,2) + '-' + 
                     substring(CAST(SomeTable.FetchTime AS VARCHAR(20)),7,2) + ' ' +
                     substring(CAST(SomeTable.FetchTime AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(CAST(SomeTable.FetchTime AS VARCHAR(20)),11,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(CAST(SomeTable.FetchTime AS VARCHAR(20)),13,2))
from      
    SomeTable
```

Or, if you are just after the single value, you could go back to the original query and simply write:

```
select  
   convert(datetime, substring(sub.Dt,1,4) + '-' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,5,2) + '-' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,7,2) + ' ' +
                     substring(sub.Dt,9,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,11,2) + ':' + 
                     substring(sub.Dt,13,2))
from      
    (select  CAST(FetchTime AS VARCHAR(20)) as Dt FROM SomeTable) sub
```

Comment: AHiggins thank you very much, you saved my day. This is what I was looking for :) Now I have all the values of the column converted to SQL DateTime format.